# createjs global getTransformedBounds

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I'd like to get an Bitmaps (or other Container) **global** bounds, i.e. the bounds of the Container on the stage after rotation, scale, position etc have been applied.

I have the following situation

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

var parent = new createjs.Container();
parent.x = 50;
parent.rotation = 90;
stage.addChild(parent);

var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://s.imgur.com/images/access/access-logo.png";
image.onload = handleImageLoad;

function handleImageLoad(event) {
    var image = event.target;
    var child = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
    parent.addChild(child);
    stage.update();

    console.assert(child.getTransformedBounds().width === 65);
    console.assert(child.getTransformedBounds().width === 187);
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/2kr23/48/

The image is 187 wide and 65 high, but after rotating it 90 degrees, I expect it to be 187 high and 65 wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EaselJS doesn't currently have a way to get the global bounds of a nested object, however there are a couple of ways you could approach this.

In your specific case, you could simply get the bounds of the parent:
`parent.getTransformedBounds().width`

https://jsfiddle.net/2kr23/51/

A more general approach would be to use `localToGlobal()` to find the position of the 4 corners in the global coordinate space, then use the min & max extents to get the transformed bounds.

Something like:

```
function getGlobalBounds(child) {
  var tl = child.localToGlobal(0, 0);
  var tr = child.localToGlobal(child.image.width, 0);
  var br = child.localToGlobal(child.image.width, child.image.height);
  var bl = child.localToGlobal(0, child.image.height);

  var minX = Math.min(tl.x, tr.x, br.x, bl.x);
  var maxX = Math.max(tl.x, tr.x, br.x, bl.x);
  var minY = Math.min(tl.y, tr.y, br.y, bl.y);
  var maxY = Math.max(tl.y, tr.y, br.y, bl.y);

  return new createjs.Rectangle(minX, minY, maxX-minX, maxY-minY);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2kr23/58/

Comment: Thank you very much gskinner. It's awesome to see you're still supporting this project.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help.